# A Fibonacci series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fibonacci-numbers

Let $F_n$ be the $n^{th}$ term of the Fibonacci sequence. That is, $F_1 = F_2 = 1$ and $F_n$ is defined recursively for $n\geq3$ by $F_n = F_{n-2}+F_{n-1}$. It is a known fact that 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}
$$

show that the series 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{F_n}{2^n}
$$

is convergent and compute its sum.

---

By the ratio test, I know the series is convergent. However, I have difficulty evaluating it. Any hints would be very helpful! Thanks.

Comment: There may be a more elegant way, but Binet's formula (google it if necessary) makes it easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the sum be $S$.

**Hint:** What is the value of $S - \frac{1}{2} S - \frac{1}{4}S $

Think about the usual way you deal with a geometric progression.

> $S - \frac{1}{2} S - \frac{1}{4}S  = \frac{1}{2} $